# Streaming Audio stops after SFSpeechRecognitionTask starts

Tags: swift, xcode, audio, speech-recognition

I'm streaming audio file and it works perfectly and I'm also doing speech recognition task and it also works perfectly. But when the below scenario occurs it stops streaming audio file.

1. I start speech recognition it detects speech perfectly
2. Now i start streaming the audio file it does not play audio after that.

Below is my code in ViewController.m

```
    //
//  ViewController.swift
//  RecordAndPlay
//
//  Created by Obaid on 8/15/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 test. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import AudioToolbox
import Speech

class ViewController: UIViewController,SFSpeechRecognizerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var imgBackground: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var lblTextValue: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var btnPlay: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var btnRepeatIt: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var microphoneButton: UIButton!
    var stringValue: String!
    var indexValue=0

    var playButton:UIButton?

    var player: AVPlayer! = nil
    var playerItem:AVPlayerItem?

    private let speechRecognizer = SFSpeechRecognizer(locale: Locale.init(identifier: "en-US"))!

    var recordButton: UIButton!
    var recordingSession: AVAudioSession!
    var audioRecorder: AVAudioRecorder!

    private var recognitionRequest: SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest?
    private var recognitionTask: SFSpeechRecognitionTask?
    private let audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()

    var arrayOfStrings: [String] = ["good morning", "good evening", "good night", "good afternoon", "well developed"]
    var arrayOfStringsURL: [String] = ["https://storage.googleapis.com/abdul-sample-bucket/test/sampl1.mp3", "http://dictionary.cambridge.org/media/english/us_pron/u/usc/uscld/uscld00580.mp3", "http://dictionary.cambridge.org/media/english/us_pron/u/usc/uscld/uscld00588.mp3", "http://dictionary.cambridge.org/media/english/us_pron/u/usc/uscld/uscld00579.mp3", "http://dictionary.cambridge.org/media/english/uk_pron/u/ukw/ukwel/ukwelde019.mp3"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        initializeSpeechRecognition()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        //createLabels()
        check_record_permission()
        lblTextValue.text=arrayOfStrings[0]
        imgBackground.backgroundColor=UIColor.yellow
        imgBackground.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 140, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.imgBackground.frame.height)

        btnPlay.setImage(UIImage(named: "play.png"), for: .normal)

        let xOrigin=self.view.frame.width - 70


        btnPlay.frame=CGRect(x:xOrigin, y: self.btnPlay.frame.origin.y, width:self.btnPlay.frame.width, height: self.btnPlay.frame.height)
        btnRepeatIt.isHidden=true
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    var btnClicked=0
    @IBAction func start_play(_ sender: UIButton){
        let url = URL(string: arrayOfStringsURL[indexValue])
        print(arrayOfStringsURL[indexValue])

        let playerItem:AVPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url!)
        player=nil
        player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
        player!.play()

        imgBackground.backgroundColor=UIColor.green
        lblTextValue.textColor=UIColor.white
        lblTextValue.text="Repeat it!"
        btnClicked=1
        microphoneButton.isHidden=false
        microphoneButton.frame=btnPlay.frame
        microphoneButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "record.png"), for: .normal)
        btnPlay.isHidden=true
        btnRepeatIt.isHidden=false
    }

    @IBAction func repeatTheSound(_ sender: UIButton){
        print("repeat the sound")
        let url = URL(string: arrayOfStringsURL[1])
        let playerItem:AVPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url!)
        player=nil
        player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
        player!.play()

    }

    func initializeSpeechRecognition(){
        microphoneButton.isHidden=true
        speechRecognizer.delegate = self

        SFSpeechRecognizer.requestAuthorization { (authStatus) in

            var isButtonEnabled = false

            switch authStatus {
            case .authorized:
                isButtonEnabled = true

            case .denied:
                isButtonEnabled = false
                print("User denied access to speech recognition")

            case .restricted:
                isButtonEnabled = false
                print("Speech recognition restricted on this device")

            case .notDetermined:
                isButtonEnabled = false
                print("Speech recognition not yet authorized")
            }

            OperationQueue.main.addOperation() {
                if(self.btnClicked==1){
                    self.btnPlay.isEnabled = isButtonEnabled
                }

            }
        }
    }



    var isAudioRecordingGranted: Bool!

    func check_record_permission()
    {
        switch AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().recordPermission() {
        case AVAudioSessionRecordPermission.granted:
            isAudioRecordingGranted = true
            break
        case AVAudioSessionRecordPermission.denied:
            isAudioRecordingGranted = false
            break
        case AVAudioSessionRecordPermission.undetermined:
            AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().requestRecordPermission() { [unowned self] allowed in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if allowed {
                        self.isAudioRecordingGranted = true
                    } else {
                        self.isAudioRecordingGranted = false
                    }
                }
            }
            break
        default:
            break
        }
    }


    //Speech Recognition

    @IBAction func microphoneTapped(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        if audioEngine.isRunning {
            audioEngine.stop()
            recognitionRequest?.endAudio()
        } else {
            startRecording()
        }
    }

    func startRecording() {

        if recognitionTask != nil {  //1
            recognitionTask?.cancel()
            recognitionTask = nil
        }

        let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()  //2
        do {
            try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord)
            try audioSession.setMode(AVAudioSessionModeMeasurement)
            try audioSession.setActive(true, with: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
        } catch {
            print("audioSession properties weren't set because of an error.")
        }

        recognitionRequest = SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest()  //3

        guard let inputNode = audioEngine.inputNode else {
            fatalError("Audio engine has no input node")
        }  //4

        guard let recognitionRequest = recognitionRequest else {
            fatalError("Unable to create an SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest object")
        } //5

        recognitionRequest.shouldReportPartialResults = true  //6

        recognitionTask = speechRecognizer.recognitionTask(with: recognitionRequest, resultHandler: { (result, error) in  //7

            var isFinal = false  //8

            if result != nil {


                self.stringValue = result?.bestTranscription.formattedString  //9



                isFinal = (result?.isFinal)!

                if(isFinal){
                    self.stringValue = self.stringValue.lowercased()
                    print(self.stringValue)
                    if(self.stringValue.contains(self.arrayOfStrings[0])){
                        self.imgBackground.backgroundColor=UIColor.green
                        self.lblTextValue.text="Well Done"
                        self.stringValue=""
                        self.updatePage()
                    }
                    else{
                        self.imgBackground.backgroundColor=UIColor.red
                        self.lblTextValue.text="Wrong! Try Again"
                        self.stringValue=""
                    }
                }

                self.stopRecording()
            }

            if error != nil || isFinal {  //10
                self.audioEngine.stop()
                inputNode.removeTap(onBus: 0)

                self.recognitionRequest = nil
                self.recognitionTask = nil

            }
        })

        let recordingFormat = inputNode.outputFormat(forBus: 0)  //11
        inputNode.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 1024, format: recordingFormat) { (buffer, when) in
            self.recognitionRequest?.append(buffer)
        }

        audioEngine.prepare()  //12

        do {
            try audioEngine.start()
        } catch {
            print("audioEngine couldn't start because of an error.")
        }

    }


    func speechRecognizer(_ speechRecognizer: SFSpeechRecognizer, availabilityDidChange available: Bool) {
        if available {
            microphoneButton.isEnabled = true
        } else {
            microphoneButton.isEnabled = false
        }
    }

    func updatePage(){
        print(indexValue)
        if(indexValue<self.arrayOfStrings.count){
            indexValue += 1
            self.imgBackground.backgroundColor=UIColor.yellow
            self.lblTextValue.textColor=UIColor.black
            self.lblTextValue.text=self.arrayOfStrings[indexValue]
            self.btnPlay.isHidden=false
            self.microphoneButton.isHidden=true
        }
        else{
            indexValue=0
        }

    }

    func stopRecording(){
        if audioEngine.isRunning {
            audioEngine.stop()
            recognitionRequest?.endAudio()
            self.recognitionTask = nil
        }
    }
}
```

startRecording() method is when I start the speechRecognition
start_play() method is when I play the audio

something is going in the background that needs to be stopped after i start speechRecognition.